# Android Virtual Device Configuration for a 7 inch tablet in Android SDK 2.3.3

Tags: android, tablet, android-virtual-device

I want to create a Android Virtual device that resembles a 7 inch tablet running Android version 2.3.3. There is nothing similar to that available in the SDK and when I try various combinations in the AVD settings it doesnt work out. I am using LCD Pixel Height and Width of 1024 X 600.

How can I create a virtual device that resembles a 7 inch tablet in the landscape mode. Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: have you tried hitting <ctrl>-F12 while the emulator is up?

Comment: Thanks.. I didnt knew that ctrl+F12 would switch the display into landscape mode...

Comment: When I do that the emulator goes into landscape mode but in that mode I cant see the keyboard if the cursor is placed in a edittext field... Also I dont think the width of the screen is still larger like a tablet. It seems smaller like a phone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great example of doing this can be found in the Amazon Kindle Fire FAQ:
https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire

> We also recommend that you test your app on your own and submit an
>   update if you discover any problems. It is possible to configure a
>   standard Android emulator to simulate the Kindle Fire device platform.
>   You should configure your emulator with the following characteristics:
>
> - Width: 600px
> - Height: 1024px
> - Abstracted LCD Density: 169
> - Target: Android 2.3.4 - API Level 10
> - RAM: 512 MB

Comment: I have the following in my AVD settings:

Target: Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10 (Cant find 2.3.4 in the SDK manager)

Skin: Built-in WVGA800

Hardware Properties:

LCD Pixel height: 1024

LCD Pixel width: 600

Abstracted LCD density: 169

RAM size: 512


But still I feel the emulator behaves/looks like a phone and not a tablet.. not sure what I am missing....

Comment: when you start it, do you use the `Scale display to real size` checkbox?

Comment: I tried the scale display checkbox but it didnt work.. rightnow, i dont use that... also i didnt find a way ofaetting that when emulator is initiated from eclipse

Comment: now keep in mind ... if you're targeting 2.3.3, that is in fact, a phone operating system. 3.0 (honeycomb) is the first android OS to target the tablet scenario, and 4.0 unifies their tablet and phone operating system into a single OS.

Comment: @Joel Then how come Samsung Galaxy Nexus has a width(px) 720 and height(px) 1184?  That would just shoot holes in your explanation.

Comment: @IgorG. remember, pixel dimensions don't really have much to do with the device's form factor. This is a high density display, so they pack that many pixels into a smaller form factor to increase resolution (think retina display from ios).

Answer (score 0):

Android Virtual Device Manager
new (name: Tablet 7inTest or whatever you want but name must not 
Exist in your emulators list)
ok very next thing you have to do is Select Resolution in Skin category type 1200x800
and click on Create AVD